# Ember JS: Mapping 3 input in a component to one value

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a component for entering a date, the component will have 3 separate input fields (date, month, year) but I would like concatenate the value of each fields into a formatted value (ex 2017-01-02) that I would bind to my model.

I am using an observer to this so if any of input change I update the formatted value. I also have an observer that listen to when the formatted changed, I update the 3 fields.

The problem seem to be when I changed the formatted value, one observer kicks in, I set the value for 3 fields, then I another observer kicks in, then formatted value kicks in, etc.

I am wondering is there easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule [don't use observers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PUX27RKCq0). In your specific case you can just use a computed property [with a setter](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties), for example:

```
day: 1,
month: 0, 
year: 2000,

formattedDate: Ember.computed('day', 'month', 'year', function(){
  get(key){
    // Create a new date from the three properties
    const date = new Date(this.get('year'), this.get('month'), this.get('day'));
    // Return the date formatted however you want it
    return date.toDateString();
  },
  set(key, value){
    // Create a new date from the value passed in
    const date = new Date(value);
    // Set the three properties 
    this.set('day', date.getDate());
    this.set('month', date.getMonth());
    this.set('year', date.getFullYear());
  }
})
```

Comment: This only works one direction, if I changed the formattedDate outside of the component, it won't update my input fields

Comment: Yeah sorry I read your question a bit too quickly, updated my answer so it's two way

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be best to put both behaviors into a single observer. Barring that you could use a mutex to "lock" the behavior of the 2nd observer, or notify it that the first observer has kicked in.

Comment: Is there way to know what field changed?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not to use an observer for this. I think the best approach is to use DDAU for this. So you have something like these inputs:

```
day:<input onchange={{action 'setDatePart' 'day' value="target.value"}} />
month:<input onchange={{action 'setDatePart' 'month' value="target.value"}} />
year:<input onchange={{action 'setDatePart' 'year' value="target.value"}} />
```

and then this action in your component:

```
actions: {
  setDatePart(part, val) {
    set(this, part, val);
    const {year, month, day} = this.getProperties('year', 'month', 'day');
    return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
  }
}
```